# Mount a device with ntfs-3g in c application

Tags: c, linux, mount

What is the good way for mounting a device with ntfs-3g driver in C application?

For mounting other filesystems i'm going to use [libmount](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.21/libmount-docs/) but what to do with ntfs-3g? I didn't find any doc for libntfs-3g.

Yes, i can use system() for this but it seems that it's not very good solution.

And also the question about detection filesystem of a device before mounting: while im going to mount a device with a loop through all the relevant filesystems until it succeeds, but maybe exist better way for this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use mount? It's very reliable and easy to debug, and if it fails you can just print the command string and run manually to fix it.

Comment: Yes, it works fine, but i don't like to use a system() in a C code, anyway i will use it if i don't find others good ways.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Linux specific mount() system call.

It allows you to mount but you need to specify the filesystem.

To detect the filesystem type you can read some data from the beginning of the device, and use libmagic to know the filesystem type.
The function magic_buffer() can help you.
I am not sure on how many bytes you need to read from the device, you can do some tests, but i think 128 bytes should be more than enough.

Comment: Yes, i know about mount() and use it by libmount and all work fine but problem with ntfs-3g, because it works by fuse. It means that i must use any lib for fuse or lib for ntfs-3g, but i didn't find any information about how to use libntfs-3g. And thank for information about detecting, actually i decided to use for this blkid/blkid.h

Comment: What is the problem with fuse?

Comment: I dont think that i can mount ntfs-3g only by using fuse's lib, it seems i need to read the libntfs-3g source code for understanding how to use this lib.